# Explorer crashing repeatedly in Win 10 Ver 1511: explorerframe.dll culprit?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, crash, event-viewer

Recently (within 3-4 days or so) my explorer has been crashing regularly but inconsistently (i.e. persistent attempts at viewing a particular folder will eventually work.) I checked the Windows Event log and found this common error message:

```
- EventData 

   explorer.exe 
   10.0.10586.0 
   5632d4c0 
   explorerframe.dll 
   10.0.10586.0 
   5632d321 
   c0000005 
   0000000000053f2e 
   5584 
   01d132f55d0abdf1 
   C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe 
   C:\WINDOWS\system32\explorerframe.dll 
   1f3995ec-3bca-4f24-b0c2-9045d90b33f7
```

The machine runs Windows 10 x64, frequently updated, no pirated software and has been working normally until the problems described above start appearing.

What should I do now please?

**Edit**:
(1) **Possible trigger(s)**:

- the update of GPU driver (Radeon Software Version 15.11)
- some impatient attempt at accessing a shared Homegroup folder: when I saw Explorer struggling, I kept spamming at it, and eventually restarted the computer

(2) **I thought I found a fix but I didn't!** I ran `sfc /scannow` at Command Prompt (with Administrator's privilege). Things were back to normal for a while but just now Explorer has crashed again. New Event log:

```
EventData 

   Explorer.EXE 
   10.0.10586.0 
   5632d4c0 
   explorerframe.dll 
   10.0.10586.0 
   5632d321 
   c0000005 
   0000000000053f2e 
   ad0 
   01d132f874810af6 
   C:\WINDOWS\Explorer.EXE 
   C:\WINDOWS\system32\explorerframe.dll 
   5bc278cb-cd58-4b93-94f1-9f054acdd799
```

Comment: sfc fixes corrupted Windows files. Maybe the Explorerframe.dll was corrupted.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks! I checked the log file from sfc /scannow and just naively did Ctrl - F and found no mention of explorerframe.dll. How do I verify that the problem is fixed? (Things have continued to work without error since last night.)

Comment: follow this: http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU. When Explorer crashes again, share the compressed dump file. I'll take a look at it with a debugger

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thank you very much. I'm at work at the moment but I'll do as instructed as soon as I get home latter this afternoon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I experienced continuous crashing of file explorer when I upgraded my windows 10 installation to version 1511. After much experimentation I fixed it by going into control panel -> appearance and personalisation -> file explorer options -> clicking 'Clear' button ie clear explorer history. Old data in the history was causing my crash. If this doesn't work try changing 'Open File Explorer To' from 'Quick Access' to 'This PC'.

Comment: +1. The problem hasn't returned just yet for now. If it does, I'll do what you've said and if that works, I'll tick this as the answer.

Comment: I'm trying this and I'll come back with an update in a week or when explorer.exe crashes, whichever happens comes first.

Comment: Aaaaaand... it crashed in 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue right now again and it was caused by having the size of text, apps etc. set to 175% in the Display Settings. Changing that to 150% 'solved' it.